# Ошибка Failed to decode downloaded font при подключении к JSP

Tags: java, jsp, maven

Подключаю к JSP bootstrap и стили для `<ul>`. Стили подключаются, но при загрузке файлов иконок woff, woff2 и ttf вылетают ошибки Failed to decode downloaded font и OTS parsing error: invalid version tag. Из-за этого иконки не отображаются. Изменял кодировку файлов на UTF-8, не помогло. При загрузке страницы из html все работает правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, все решилось следующим образом: файлы font, bootstrap, jquery я подключил через cdn. При этом почему то кнопки glyphicon стали уже по высоте, пришлось подправить их стилями. Теперь все работает правильно.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml должен быть вот таким :

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: это для картинок , иконок и.т.д ..

Comment: png стали отображаться, но для файлов c расширением woff2, svg и прочих это не сработало. В своем проекте я не использую Spring и поэтому я не стал сначала добавлять фильтр, а добавил маппинг по аналогии для нужных мне расширений, но это не помогло. Затем я все же добавил dependency на `<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>`, и вставил Ваш код, но это не помогло. Также я пытался добавить filter-class от tomcat' a, но его вообще не нашло

Comment: `<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>` - был такой класс для фильтра и зависимость `<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>`

Comment: Нашел ошибку с томкатом: в зависимости я указывал 7 версию и поэтому не находило необходимый класс. Исправил зависимость, класс нашелся, но по прежнему не работает

Comment: В первом комментарии под словами "Ваш код" я подразумевал часть про описание фильтра и его маппинг, без DispatcherServlet Sping'a

Comment: почему не используете сразу со спрингом ?если что вот готовый апп https://github.com/AltynbekAndr/WebSiteForWebStudy app на спринге.Тут используются bootstrap и png файлы и еще много чего, если посмотрите в Pom.XML.Настроено подключение в СУБД MySQL.

Comment: все настройки по мапингам в mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml..Деплоил в 7-м томкате.

Comment: Проект в учебных целях, решил спринг пока не использовать.